# Change line pattern in file.txt if the first one is larger

Tags: bash

Hi everyone I have actually a `file.txt` with a lot of lines such as:

```
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 5000-3000 >> file.fst

blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 1-500 >> file.fst

blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 6000-2000 >> file.fst

blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 340-670 >> file.fst
```

As you can see at the `-range` part sometime the first number is larger than the second and something the first one is smaller. 
And I would like when the first number is larger than the second to change the line by interchanging them.
Here in the exemple it would be:

```
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 3000-5000 >> file.fst

blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 1-500 >> file.fst

blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 2000-6000 >> file.fst

blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 340-670 >> file.fst
```

Do you think it is possible? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: `file.txt` seems an odd name for what appears to be a shell script.  Can you re-factor the script?  eg, something like `blast() {  if test "$1" -gt "$2"; then a=$2; b=$1; else a=$1; b=$2; fi; blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui_ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range ${a}-${b} >> file.fst; }`

Comment: It is a txt file where several line will be run with the commande : for line in read -r file.txt line ; do command "$line"; done

Comment: It is certainly possible. With perl, it's a one-liner. Please show the efforts you have made to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @bewolf, given your comment to William, you should read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and also https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{split($(NF-2),array,"-"); if(array[1]>array[2]){$(NF-2)=array[2] "-" array[1]}; print}' file
```

Split third last element (`$(NF-2)`) with `split()` to an array, compare its elements and reassemble third last element (`$(NF-2)=array[2] "-" array[1]`).

Output:

```
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 3000-5000 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 1-500 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 2000-6000 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 340-670 >> file.fst
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 2):

perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=-range )(\d+)-(\d+)/ ($a,$b) = $1 < $2 ? ($1,$2) : ($2,$1); "$a-$b" /e' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible.  Here is a quick-n-dirty solution.  It can be made more robust, according to the needs / context:

**so2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read linein; do
    #echo $linein            ## uncomment for debugging

    rangeA=`echo $linein | sed 's/^.* -range \([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
    rangeB=`echo $linein | sed 's/^.* -range [0-9]*-\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
    #echo $rangeA $rangeB    ## uncomment for debugging

    if [[ $rangeA -gt $rangeB ]]; then
        echo "blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range ${rangeB}-${rangeA} >> file.fst"
    else
        echo "blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range ${rangeA}-${rangeB} >> file.fst"
    fi
done < so2.in
```

**so2.in**

```
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 5000-3000 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 1-500 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 6000-2000 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 340-670 >> file.fst
```

**`./so2.sh`**

```
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 3000-5000 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 1-500 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 2000-6000 >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db path/db_ui/ode -entry scaffold_XXX -range 340-670 >> file.fst
```